# How to get object array value from response array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get object array value from response array? Below is my code to send Ajax request

```
var post_data = {
    "user_name_title" : $scope.user_name_title,
};
$http.post(url,post_data).then(function(res)
{
    console.log(res['Message']);
},
```

**Output is**

```
{
  "ResponseCode": 200,
  "Data": [],
  "Message": "Data inserted successfully.",
  "Error": []
}
```

How can I get the result objects, I have used

> console.log(res['Message']);

but it showing undefined. What should I use?

Comment: That looks like it should work, can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Error - Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `.then` over `$http` method, you should get API response data inside `data` property of response object, like below.

```
console.log(res.data['Message']);
```